# What's behind a URL?

Tags: url

What are the parts that make up a url? I'm kinda confused about how a "url" works. I understand it's a "path" to a location on the internet, but what do they mean?

For example: serverfault.com

`serverfault` is in relation I assume the name of the page you're looking for, but what does the `.com` part really represent? In short, I know it implies it's a commercial site, but what does the `.xxx` part represent? Is it suppose to represent a subdomain or something?

How can you explain a URL easy enough for most people to understand?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax

Comment: Also, what's "www" used for? Ex if you enter "www.serverfault.com", it'll do the exact same thing that typing "serverfault.com" does, so is it only a placeholder?

Comment: I'll update my answer with that information.

Answer (score 6):

Let's break this example down briefly: `http://www.serverfault.com/questions`.

- `http://` - the protocol used (HTTP in this case)
- `www` - the third level domain, sometimes used as a hostname.  Also frequently called a subdomain.
- `.serverfault` - the second level domain, which is registered with a domain registrar
- `.com` - the top level domain
- `.` - the root domain.  This is implied, although not written in standard URL notation.  Thus the full domain name is actually "`serverfault.com.`"
- `/questions/` - the actual directory or page requested at serverfault.com.

Each subsequent level after the root (root-> TLD -> SLD -> Subdomain/host) provides increasing specificity, in theory.

The structure of web page URLs is also closely linked with the way [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) operates.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier) has more complete information.